# shortest notation for "set of all maps from $A$ to $B$"?

Tags: notation

I usually write the following:

$$\{m| m:A\to B\}$$

Is there a more succint notation?

Answer (score 4):

The standard notation is $B^A$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this notation have a name?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Examples) doesn't list any name.

Comment: @Programmer2134 Although I can't find a name, this notation seems to be derived from [cardinal exponentiation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CardinalExponentiation.html) and is related to the common notation of $2^B$ for the powerset of $B$. So, if you want to give a name for the notation, something like "function exponentiation notation" or "powerfunction notation" might work. Then again, a lot of notation is generally unnamed and this isn't seen as a problem.

Answer (score 3):

$A \to B$ is a common notation for the set of functions. For instance

$$
\begin{array}{l}
f : (A\to B)\times A \to B \\
f(g,x) = g(x)
\end{array}
$$